# C Style String palindrome detector (case insensitive) in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, c-strings, palindrome

I've been trying to create a program that takes a C style string from the user and answers if it's a palindrome or not. I've built a function (purg) that takes out all non-lowercase letters (and turns uppercase ones to lowercase). And another that returns true or false if it's a palindrome or not. The purg function can print the modified string as intended (e.g. "Race 111 car" is printed as "racecar"), but the palindrome function does not flag that modified string as a palindrome, what is wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

bool isit(char *test, int u){
   char *well = test;
   bool chk = false;

   for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
     if (well[i] != well[u-i-1]) {
       return false;
     }
     cout << well[i];
   }
   return true;
}

void purg(char *ini){
  int x = 0;
  bool answ;
  char *elim = ini;

  for (int i = 0; ini[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (ini[i] >= 'A' && ini[i] <= 'Z') {
      elim[i] = ini[i] + 32;
      x++;
    } else if (!(ini[i] >= 'a' && ini[i] <= 'z')) {
      elim[i]='\0';
    } else{
      x++;
    }
    cout << elim[i]; //This reliably prints the answer I expect ("11race car_!" to "racecar")
  }
  answ = isit(&elim[0], x); //Is this passed correctly?
  cout << endl;
  if (answ == true){
    cout << "It is a palindrome." << endl; //(user inputs like "RACecar", "racecar111", "racecar" and "WAAAAW111" are correct)
  } else {
    cout << "No palindrome here..." << endl; //("race car", "1racecar", and "d1o1d" are not, but they print as expected "racecar" and "dod")
  }
}

int main(){
   string str;//I'm not supposed to use C++ strings, should I replace this with char str[512]={}?

   cout<<"Give me a string"<<endl;
   getline(cin,str);

   purg(&str[0]);   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The purg function can print the modified string as intended" how do you read this intent? Is it a requirement of your assignment that all non A-Z, a-z characters be removed? If it's not a requirement, the easy thing to do is trust that the user knows what they're inputting.

Comment: It is required to get rid of all non-a-z characters and to replace all uppercase letters to lower case. Regarding the passing the char array with '\0', I'm really at a loss on how to do it otherwise.

Comment: Maybe just construct a new string that contains only the characters you want to test, and pass that to `isit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's separate your code into two distinct functions with two distinct purposes, so we can talk about them separately:

### Purge non letters from the string

#### Your code:

```c
void purge(char *ini) {
  int x = 0;
  bool answ;
  char *elim = ini;

  for (int i = 0; ini[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (ini[i] >= 'A' && ini[i] <= 'Z') {
      elim[i] = ini[i] + 32;
      x++;
    } else if (!(ini[i] >= 'a' && ini[i] <= 'z')) {
      elim[i]='\0';
    } else{
      x++;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Main issue with this code:

What is `x` supposed to do? It looks like it's supposed to track the number of valid characters, but you never use it. In fact, if we run a test:

```c
char s[256] = "a!bc";
purge(s);
ASSERT_EQ("abc", s); // This fails, purge changed the string s into just "a".
```

#### How can we fix this?

Well, by using `x`!

```c
void purge(char *str) {
  int x = 0;

  for (int i = 0; ini[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') {
      str[x] = str[i] - 'A' + 'a';
      x++;
    } else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
      str[x] = str[i];
      x++;
    }
  }
  // Make sure we null terminate the new string.
  str[x] = '\0';
}
```

### Test if a string is a Palindrome

#### Your code:

```c
bool is_palindrome(char *test, int u){
   char *well = test;
   bool chk = false;

   for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
     if (well[i] != well[u-i-1]) {
       return false;
     }
     cout << well[i];
   }
   return true;
}
```

#### Issues with the code:

1. Bad variable names. What's `u` supposed to be? What's `well` supposed to be?
2. Why are you only looping from `i=0..2`?

#### How we might fix this...

```c
bool is_palindrome(char *str, int str_length) {
  for (int i = 0; i < str_length / 2; i++) {
    if (str[i] != str[str_length - i - 1]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

### Other thoughts

By rewriting the code as two separate functions, we can start to add tests to this code. For example, we could use google's unit test infrastructure to do something like:

```cpp
TEST(MyTests, Purge_Nothing) {
  char a[256] = "abc";
  purge(a);
  EXPECT_EQ(std::string("abc"), a);
}

TEST(MyTests, Purge_Non_Letters_At_Front) {
  char a[256] = "!abc";
  purge(a);
  EXPECT_EQ(std::string("abc"), a);
}

TEST(MyTests, Purge_Non_Letter_In_Middle) {
  char a[256] = "ab!c";
  purge(a);
  EXPECT_EQ(std::string("abc"), a);
}

TEST(MyTests, Purge_Non_Letters_At_End) {
  char a[256] = "abc!";
  purge(a);
  EXPECT_EQ(std::string("abc"), a);
}

TEST(MyTests, Purge_Uppercase) {
  char a[256] = "Abc!";
  purge(a);
  EXPECT_EQ(std::string("abc", a);
}

TEST(MyTests, Palindrome) {
  EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome("abcba");
  EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome("abba"));
  EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome("aba"));
  EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome("aa"));
  EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome("z"));
  EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome(""));
  EXPECT_FALSE(is_palindrome("abcda");
  EXPECT_FALSE(is_palindrome("abda");
  EXPECT_FALSE(is_palindrome("abd");
  EXPECT_FALSE(is_palindrome("ad");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After a quick skim of your code - it seems you replace all non-alphabetic characters with '\0', and then expect the string that contains random '\0' characters to pass the palindrome test, which tests for character equality, treating '\0' as a regular character that must be matched with a mirror '\0' from the other side.

Also, you pass the full length string, that includes the '\0' characters, to the `isit` function, but only give the number of the non-replaced characters as the length.

The reason your string appears to be printed correctly, is that when you print '\0', it just does nothing. Look at the contents of `ini` with a debugger and you will see that it is really littered with those replaced '\0' characters.

Try giving it a string that does not contains any non-alphabetic characters, it should pass, if I'm correct.

Comment: Without any modification of the code, user inputs like "madam" return the expected "It is a palindrome". "a1a" and "1aa" do not register as a palindrome whilst "aa1" does. The reason behind it is beyond me though.

Comment: I think I explained everything that's going on & why it's failing.

Comment: @BigBoss: Your prune function translates "a1a" into the string "a\0a" with a string length recorded as 2. Your palindrome code then tries to check if str[0] == str[1], which is false and it incorrectly fails. Because the prune didn't prune correctly.

Comment: @BigBoss: It's the same for `1aa`. Your prune converts that to a string of `"\0aa"` with a length of 2. The comparison fails again because the prune didn't prune correctly.

Answer (score 0):

C example of case insensitive function for palindrome testing. You may use it as is in C++ code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int is_palindrome(const char * str) {
    const char * tail = str + strlen(str) - 1;

    for ( ; str < tail && toupper(*str) == toupper(*tail); ++str, --tail )
        ;

    return str >= tail;
}
```